# Symfony - Duplicate key when i created new entity

Tags: php, symfony, key, entity

Ok guys simple and quick question how can i create multiples new entities without having the error "duplicate entry ... for key 'UNIQ'" i do it like this :

```
    $userInterest_1 = new UserInterest();
    $userInterest_2 = new UserInterest();
    $userInterest_3 = new UserInterest();
```

But userInterest 1 2 and 3 has the same id key so how can i create 3 entities without having the same key : (i tried to persist and flush before create anew one that don't work)

Sooo that's all if you want i put all my code if that can help thx for all that will try to answer :)

```
$em_category = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $userInterest_1 = new UserInterest();
    $userInterest_1->setUser($user);
    $category_1 = $em_category->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => ($request->get('id_category_1'))));
    if ($category_1 === NULL) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Categorie 1 non renseignée"
        ]);
    }
    $userInterest_1->setContent($request->get('content_1'));
    $userInterest_1->setCategory($category_1);
    $em->persist($userInterest_1);
    $em->flush();

    $userInterest_2 = new UserInterest();
    $userInterest_2->setUser($user);
    $category_2 = $em_category->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => ($request->get('id_category_2'))));
    if ($category_2 === NULL) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Categorie 2 non renseignée"
        ]);
    }
    $userInterest_2->setContent($request->get('content_2'));
    $userInterest_2->setCategory($category_2);
    $em->persist($userInterest_2);
    $em->flush();


    $userInterest_3 = new UserInterest();
    $userInterest_3->setUser($user);
    $category_3 = $em_category->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => ($request->get('id_category_3'))));
    if ($category_3 === NULL) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Categorie 3 non renseignée"
        ]);
    }
    $userInterest_3->setContent($request->get('content_3'));
    $userInterest_3->setCategory($category_3);
    $em->persist($userInterest_3);
    $em->flush();
```

My json POST method look like this :

```
{
"username": "eTytyoftyooy6o7o",
"password": "Tsvyfviftypooyotô7uo",
"email": "ls.sivpdtrokt63@gmal.com",
"birth": "1999-04-26T18:25:43-05:00",
"id_category_1": "1",
"content_1": "Dog",
"id_category_2": "4",
"content_2": "Tennis",
"id_category_3": "5",
"content_3": "Netflix"
```

}

or maybe should i do something like that (but i don't know how to receive an arrray) :

```
{
"username": "eTytyoftyooy6o7o",
"password": "Tsvyfviftypooyotô7uo",
"email": "ls.sivpdtrokt63@gmal.com",
"birth": "1999-04-26T18:25:43-05:00",
"category": [{
    "id_category_1": "1",
    "content_1": "Chien",
},
    "id_category_2": "4",
    "content_2": "Tennis",
},
    "id_category_3": "5",
    "content_3": "Dora"
}]
}
```

ps : the code as no error that work when i flush only one and the second as the good values only id is the same as the one before :) (and my id is in strategie= AUTO)

(someone's maybe see me a lot in symfony forum but i am trying to learn by my own so you guys are my teachers)

Edit : i add the entities :

UserInterest entity

```
 /**
 * UserInterest
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_interest")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserInterest
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="category", inversedBy="intrests")
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * @param string $content
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * @param User $user
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $category
 */
public function setCategory($category)
{
    $this->category = $category;
}

}
```

Category entity :

```
/**
* UserInterest
*
* @ORM\Table(name="category")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Category
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content_c", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserInterest", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $interests;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * @param string $content
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;
}

/**
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param User $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

}
```

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure "xD" is understood anywhere but in France, and "catégorie" is feminin so "renseigné" should be written "renseignée" in your response. What you are looking for is relation. If you're working with Symfony 4, the maker bundle allows you to create an Entity with relations, which would return the array as in your second example (probably many-to-many relationship), which is a better thing to do. Think about how the app will evolve. It would have been interesting to be able to see your entities too

Comment: I am using sumfony 3.4 is that the same with this version ? (and my relation is many to one)

Comment: Is your id set properly (with autoincrement)? If you are learning, maybe you should take a look at symfony 4

Comment: yes it is (sorry for not saying i will edit my post)

Comment: and i have to use symfony 3.4 ... what should i do ?

Comment: Did you rely on doctrine cli to create your entities or did you make it by yourself ? Can we see it (update your question) ?

Comment: i update my entities :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have that problem. I've been always using that method and it always creates entities with different ID's.
Anyways, you can check for the last ID of your table and assign the next one to the new entity. That must solve the problem.

Comment: i do like $userInterest_3->setId($userInterest_3->getId() +1); and don't work same error

Comment: I meant something like a query to get the last id of the table. Calling getId() in those objects won't solve anything. Count the items of the table and you should get your id, or query them by ID desc and check the ID of the first one.

Comment: Also you should check if the ID field is auto-incremental. If you're using Doctrine you should see something like 
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") above the field in your class.

Comment: Yes it is is a strategy = auto what does that change